# Traditional installer for a WinForms application

Tags: c#, winforms, installer

What is the preferred method of creating a "normal" traditional installer for a .NET WinForms application? I'm using VS 2015 which comes without a template for such a deployment project. I installed it as a separate extension and everything is actually alive more or less, building the .msi which even works fine.

But for example I am running into the major trouble trying to include building the installer into my CI pipeline, to make the installer always available for the latest build. Apparently, these projects cannot be built by msbuild and require VS installed on the integration machine? This makes the whole thing look dated at best (or obsolete actually).

Is there an "official" way to work with installers in VS? Besides Clickonce, that is?

Comment: I used to use [WIX](http://wixtoolset.org/) back when I wrote windows applications (in the past 5 years I have done nothing but web applications). At the time I found it highly flexible and extensible, never ran into anything I could not do with it. An alternative is InstallShield. There is an [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3156376/1260204) about comparing the 2.

Comment: We use WiX, too, it is fully scriptable and AFAIK does not require VS to be installed in the integration machine (though it comes with a nice VS integration). Besides that, tool recommendations are off-topic for this site.

Comment: Take a look into Squirrel; it may help https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows